# TSQL: Nested Try-Catch does not capture inner catch

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I have the following stored procedure statement:

```
DECLARE @CurrentId BIGINT
DECLARE @FailedRecord NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

BEGIN TRY -- 1st Try
    INSERT INTO #tmpNewApp
        SELECT Id, Email, Content 
        FROM dbo.NewApplication

    WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #tmpNewApp)
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY -- 2nd Try
            SET @CurrentId = (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM #tmpNewApp)

            INSERT INTO EmailSending
                SELECT Email, Content 
                FROM #tmpNewApp 
                WHERE Id = @CurrentId
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH -- 2nd Catch
            SET @FailedRecord = @FailedRecord + ', ' + @CurrentId;
        END CATCH

        DELETE FROM #tmpNewApp 
        WHERE Id = @CurrentId
    END
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH -- 1st Catch
    INSERT INTO DatabaseException
    SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE(), GETDATE()
END CATCH

SELECT @FailedRecord
```

I'm trying to get list of IDs that hit exception during the loop. However,  `@FailedRecord` always returns empty and `DatabaseException` always able to catch the exception, which seems like the second `CATCH` got captured by the first `CATCH` and the statement in the second `CATCH` just got ignored.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

@FailedRecord always return empty - you 2nd catch always return error "Error converting data type varchar to bigint."

1. Use convert/cast you BigInt

   SET @FailedRecord = @FailedRecord + ', ' + Cast(@CurrentId as VARCHAR(20))
2. 1st Try/Catch works only error in (or error conversion :))

   INSERT INTO #tmpNewApp    SELECT Id, Email,Content FROM dbo.NewApplication

Move insert into DatabaseException on 2nd Catch or test value and store error messsage in variable

```
 IF @FailedRecord <> ''
```